# TYPO3: How can I access property of objects in a partial or section?

Tags: typo3

I have an object defined in TypoScript

```
page.10 {
  variables {
    myObject = COA
    myObject{
     1 = TEXT
     1.value = yome Text
     2 = TEXT
     2.value = 42
    }
  }
}
```

and I need the data of the myObject in a partial

```
<f:render partial="myPartial" arguments="{content:myObject}" />
```

that looks like

```
<section id="myPartial">
<h2>{content.1}</h2>
<p>{content.2}</p>
</section>
```

Although the content is there ( because {content} will display all the properties) I cannot access it and h2 and p will be empty...

What should I do to fill h2 and p with the content of myObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. `TypoScript` only returns text strings at the moment, not arrays. Thus the variable `myObject` contains the whole concatenated string of the `COA`, thus `yome Text42`.

Note that `COA` means `Content Object Array`, but the whole `COA` is **one** single object that is returned as **one** string.

Comment: I see. So I need to write a View Helper with an own Controller, right?

Comment: Or you need to split the data into multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: use the `VHS` extension's `v:var.typoscript` ViewHelper:

```
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
{v:var.typoscript(path: 'page.10.variables.myObject') -> v:var.set(name: 'myObject')}
```

After which you can access `{myObject.1}` etc. in your template. Note that the so-called "chained" usage of `v:var.set` is **optional**, *but will make it easier to access your variables using an intermediate template variable instead of more expensive calls to retrieve the value completely in multiple locations*. The other way:

```
{v:var.typoscript(path: 'page.10.variables.myObject.1')}
{v:var.typoscript(path: 'page.10.variables.myObject.2')}
etc.
```

VHS extension on TER: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/vhs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FLUIDTEMPLATE.settings` to provide custom data to the view.
In your case:

```
page.10.settings {
  myObject {
    foo = bar
    bar = foo
  }
}
```

The partial call should look like this:

```
<f:render partial="myPartial" arguments="{content:settings.myObject}" />
```